# Unable to boot the RDS inside a VPC in GCP

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, terraform

I need to boot the RDS of Postgres inside a VPC. I need the code of Google Provider.

I have Tried official terraform.io and also github **https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraform-google-sql-db/blob/227b1ec7a830622560bff85194a816638be1c7c5/examples/mysql-and-postgres/main.tf#L82** but didnt have any luck

```
  name                 = "name"
  project              = "project_name"
  region               = "us-east-1"
  database_version     = "${var.database_version}"


  settings {
    tier                        = "${var.machine_type}"

    ip_configuration {
        ipv4_enabled = true
        authorized_networks = {
          name  = "${data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.outputs.network_name}"
          value = "10.10.22.0/24"
        }

    }
```

i had also tried

```
ip_configuration = [{
    private_network = "${var.network_cird_range}"
  }]
```

"I expect the RDS to be boot inside a VPC , but i couldn't find any luck. can anyone help me out here 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get an error? Can you edit your question to include the error? It would also be helpful if the Terraform code in your question was a [mcve] instead of so heavily truncated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your issue correctly, you are getting an error while creating a Google Cloud SQL instance with Private IP using Terraform, am I right? if so, here is my code to achieve what you want:

```tf
provider "google" {
 credentials = "${file("CREDENTIALS.json")}"
 project     = "PROJECT-ID"
 region      = "us-central1"
}
resource "google_compute_network" "private_network" {
    name       = "testnw"
}

resource "google_compute_global_address" "private_ip_address" {
    provider="google"
    name          = "${google_compute_network.private_network.name}"
    purpose       = "VPC_PEERING"
    address_type = "INTERNAL"
    prefix_length = 16
    network       = "${google_compute_network.private_network.name}"
}

resource "google_service_networking_connection" "private_vpc_connection" {
    provider="google"
    network       = "${google_compute_network.private_network.self_link}"
    service       = "servicenetworking.googleapis.com"
    reserved_peering_ranges = ["${google_compute_global_address.private_ip_address.name}"]
}

resource "google_sql_database_instance" "instance" {
    provider="google"
    depends_on = ["google_service_networking_connection.private_vpc_connection"]
    name = "privateinstance"
    region = "us-central1"
    settings {
        tier = "db-f1-micro"
        ip_configuration {
            ipv4_enabled = "false"
            private_network = "projects/PROJECT-ID/global/networks/${google_compute_network.private_network.name}"
        }
    }
}
```

This code will create a VPC NW, then will [allocate an IP range](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-services-access#allocating-range) automatically, then will create a ["service networking peering"](https://cloud.google.com/service-infrastructure/docs/service-networking/getting-started), and after that, a Cloud SQL instance with private IP.

Comment: Hi Alex,
 thanks for the interest but i am looking for the code in Google provider. I have my whole infra booted up with "Google" provider. So please share if you have any reference in google provider rather than "Goog-beta" Provider. 
And What you have understood is right. Thanks @Alex Riquelme

Comment: @tejeshsurabathula Sorry, I created this code when the private IP feature for CSQL was still in beta. Now is GA and you should be able to use the "google" provider, I'll edit my code, it will be exactly the same, but with "google", instead of "google-beta" in the "provider" section.

Comment: @Akex Riquelme 
I had tried the code which you have said above. but still getting the error

```* module.rds.google_sql_database_instance.default: "settings.0.ip_configuration.0.private_network" ("test/temporal-studio-234307/global/networks/network") doesn't match regexp "projects/((?:(?:[-a-z0-9]{1,63}\\.)*(?:[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?):)?(?:[0-9]{1,19}|(?:[a-z0-9](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?)))/global/networks/((?:[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?))$"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue when I tried to use Google Terraform Module to create a PostgreSQL managed instance. In my case, I'm fixing that using this:

```
private_network = "projects/PROJECT_ID/global/networks/NETWORK_NAME"
```

Try this and let me know if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the **private_network** this way:

```
private_network = google_compute_network.private_network.self_link
```